# How can i print the amount of unique words in this doc.txt file / why doesn't it work?

Tags: python, function, dictionary, for-loop, text-files

- Problem: Need to output the amount of unique words within this doc.txt file which should be **16** (no dupes), and i can't seem to find why it doesn't do so.
- Note: The black lines are just my user which includes a space e.g. Will Smith & i don't expect full help on this project i just can't seem to find a solution to this issue, and this is a last resort, apologies.

Code Image:

[image]

What I've tried:

- I've tried changing the file path, the function parameter name, methods to call the function, including "/" where the spaces are.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Please provide your code as text, so we can read and test it more easily. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: In what sense does your code not work? Do you actually call your *dictionary_1()* function somewhere else in your code?

Answer (score 0):

A set would make things easier. For example:

```
with open('file.txt') as infile:
  contents = infile.read()
  myset = set(contents.split())
  print(len(myset)) # the number of unique words
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import string

def dictionary_1(path):
    dictionary = {}
    read_file = None

    # properly read file
    with open(path, "r") as text_file:
        read_file = text_file.read()
    
    # remove punctuation marks
    read_file = read_file.translate(str.maketrans('','', string.punctuation))

    dictionary = {word:[] for word in read_file.split()}
    # for word in unique_words:
    #     dictionary.setdefault(word, [])

    print("Words in dictionary: ", len(dictionary))
    print(dictionary)
```

And always make sure not to use python keywords(**dict**, **list**, ...) as variable name